# How do I know which enemy aspects I hand out to my players?

Tags: fate-accelerated

We've been doing FATE Accelerated very frequently, and we're really beginning to like it.

Our game is based on the Gantz manga/anime in a way, since thew characters have to go every week to kill a titanic monster in order to keep themselves alive in a game they can't get out of. It's a campaign all about "monster of the week" concept with high action: the characters NEVER have time to stop and talk about the monster or even make an investigation about the weaknesses of the creatures, they're just thrown into a battlefield they're confined in and try to survive.

This experience can be quite frustrating to them, as there are enemies that seem impossible to defeat, but all of them have a weakness they can try to exploit, alongside various elements on the battlegrounds they can use to gain an advantage.

The problem here is that my players don't really like to think, and the first thing that happens is asking for Clever rolls in order to find out an enemy aspect, which I hand out however I want to, and usually not the best aspect they can use.

The book doesn't says anything about how you "forcefully" get to know an enemy aspect or stuff, nor how to hand them out...any tips?

Comment: The question posed in the title seems different than the question in the body.  Are you asking how to decide which aspect the players get based on their actions?  Or how to give them out in general?

Answer (score 1):

Getting to know an enemy aspect "forcefully" would probably involve the trial and error method. "I hit him with that! Well, that didn't seem to work. I hit him with the other thing!"